# How to pass jquery var to ui dialog and change the jquery var into PHP var

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I need some help with figuring out how to pass a jquery var (which used to be a php var), to a ui dialog and then transform that var into PHP var.

On my adminstration.php I have some radio buttons with a value pulled from my database.

With some jQuery that changes the value according to which of the radio button that has been pressed:

```
function select_user(){
        var id = null;
        $('input[name="user_id"]').on("click", function(){ //This is the radio button
            if ($(this).prop("checked", true)) {
                var id = $(this).val();
                $("#delete_user").prop("href", "delete_user.php?id=" + id);
            }else{
                var id = null;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

What I'm looking for is, to take that user_id and pass it to the dialog by pressing a delete button: 
Delete

What I think I've figured out is that I need to use .data() (I'm not sure though, cause it hasn't work so far).  However, I was trying to change the "delete_user.php?id=3" for example, but I couldn't figure out if I was on the right track or not.It looks something like this.

```
$("#delete_user").click(function() {
        $("#dialog-placeholder").load("delete_user.php").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: "auto",
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete user": function() {
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                  location.reload(true);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Because I'm not writing PHP in object (and have no idea how to), I'm writing it in the "old" way, so it's all in the same page. 
I then somehow need to take that jquery var caught in the dialog and change it into a php var.

If there are anyone who can point me in the right direction, it's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your button to activate a php function, you must use an ajax request. so to pass the variable to php, package it in your ajax request.

```
<script>
var someJqueryVar;
var url="targat.php?val="+someJqueryVar;
$.ajax( url ) 
//...
</script>
```